# How to read the complete result of ftp transfer in storeFile() in FTPClient?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

My question is regarding [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). I need detailed reply statistics. When I use `getReplyString()` I get only part of the information. 
For example:
My code is

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
//some code here
ftp.storeFile(hostDir + fileName, input);
System.out.println(ftp.getReplyString());// This prints "226 Transfer OK" when it is sucessful
```

But I need to get the statistics which we get it when we do ftp manually using command prompt as in

```
226 Transfer OK
ftp: 50 bytes sent in 0.09Seconds 0.55Kbytes/sec.
```

How to get these stats using FTPClient? Any idea or link to refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this manually, recording the start and end of the process. After, just some calculations, like: fileLength / timeEnd - timeStart. You should work a little more in these calculations.